# std::map iteration turns wrong on first run

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a std::map to store pointers to objects associated with their respective ID. When I loop on the map to get the content of it, I get a wrong return on first try, but a correct one on next tries:

```cpp
class session_list {
private:
    ...
  static std::map<uint, session*> session_list;
    ...
public:
    ...
  static void add_exclusive_session(uint id, session& session);
    ...
  std::map<uint, session*>& get_session_list() ;
};
```

```cpp
std::map<uint, core_base_session*>& core_session_list::get_session_list() {
    return session_list;
}

void session_list::add_exclusive_session(uint id, session& session) {
    guard g(mutex);
    if (session.disconnect_reason != core_sd_connected)
         return;
    session * previous_session = get_session(id, g);
    session_list.emplace(id, &session);
    if ((previous_session != nullptr)
        &&(previous_session != &session)) {
    previous_session->disconnect(core_sd_peer_duplicated);
  }
}
```

```cpp
std::map<uint, session*> session_list =
    session.parent.session_list->get_session_list();
for ( auto& it: session_list) {
    printf("\n\tSESSION N° %d \t %p" , it.first, it.second);
}
```

It dumps this :

```
2016-08-18 14:57:23.103881 [info] DBG_

        SESSION N° 1402969504    0x7efc400008c0 <=== APPEARS TWICE
        SESSION N° 574745422     0x1a469f0
        SESSION N° 1402969504    0x7efc400008c0 <=== APPEARS TWICE
        SESSION N° 1502939797    0x7efc48000ca0
        SESSION N° 1510611043    0x7efc3c000ca0
2016-08-18 14:57:38.245280 [info] DBG_

        SESSION N° 2011917896    0x7efc44000ca0 <=== APPEARS NOT ON FIRST TRY
        SESSION N° 574745422     0x1a469f0
        SESSION N° 1402969504    0x7efc400008c0
        SESSION N° 1502939797    0x7efc48000ca0
        SESSION N° 1510611043    0x7efc3c000ca0
```

Any idea?

Comment: Would you post `get_session_list` code ?

Comment: My first guess would be that the first `DBG_` output is actually output from *two* executions of the snippet in question, displayed back-to-back.

Comment: Are you sure the list of sessions didn't change during the fifteen seconds between the log records?  You're likely to have to produce an MCVE ([MCVE]), and you're likely to find it hard to produce an MCVE that reproduces the problem, IMO.  But without us knowing a lot more about what's going on, we won't be able to help much, I think.

Comment: @NPE `DBG_` output is the execution from the same snippet shown above, twice.

Comment: @RichardDally `session.parent.session_list` is an object with a std::map as private attribute. the `get_session_list()` method is public and just return the std::map

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have to try because there is a mutex story under, but I don't think it is related.

Comment: You didn't show how the `map` is created, so there is no point in us speculating on the infinite possible things that might be wrong. UB is hard enough to diagnose, without you not providing anything to use. "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working**?") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler After a few tests, it is not mutex related. Same thing in monothreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what we appear to see here is that a `std::map` object contains two identical keys. Let's enumerate the possibilities that would explain this behaviour (from least likely to most likely):

- your compiler's `std::map` is fundamentally broken and allows multiple identical keys;
- you have an undefined behaviour somewhere in your code that corrupts `session_list`;
- the first sequence of `SESSION N°` lines is produced by the code in question getting executed more than once, e.g.

  ```
  # run 1
  SESSION N° 1402969504    0x7efc400008c0 <=== APPEARS TWICE
  # run 2
  SESSION N° 574745422     0x1a469f0
  SESSION N° 1402969504    0x7efc400008c0 <=== APPEARS TWICE
  SESSION N° 1502939797    0x7efc48000ca0
  SESSION N° 1510611043    0x7efc3c000ca0
  ```

My money's on the last one. It's hard to tell how likely it is without seeing more of your code.

Comment: My compiler is standard GNU g++
g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

Comment: I don't get your 3rd point. There is two runs of the `DBG_` command. This command run the snippet once.

Comment: That version of `g++` and its library `libstdc++`, due to being included in Debian Stable, clearly cannot have a `map` so "fundamentally broken" as this... so it's not the implementation's fault.

Comment: @MicroCheapFx: There is nothing about `DBG_` in the code you've posted, so we can only guess when and how it gets printed.

Comment: @NPE It is a real pain in the ... to reproduce completely. But DBG_ is a network command which just produce the snippet output. Since there is a thread business under the carpet I think I guess what you meant now.

Comment: Since the keys must be increasing in the map, it's a different spot that is likely the break between two executions of the loop.